# GLSL Making LOD curves from lines

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader, tesselation

Solution: [Drawing tessallated LineLoops in OpenGL/GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883460/drawing-tessallated-lineloops-in-opengl-glsl)

---

I am using OpenGL and GLSL to draw LineLoops on a sphere (Borders on a Planet).

Since the points defining the lines are given by user input they do not have high enough precion to prevent clipping inside the sphere.

I want to use Tesselation and/or Geometry Shaders to create extra points in between existing points so the distance between points does not exceed a certain value (lines no longer clip inside the sphere).

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Sadly there is not much information about Tesselation Shaders, so I am not quite sure how they work, but I know that I can subdivide primitives with them.

Here is my current vertexShader:

```
#version 400

in layout(location = 0) vec3 position;

uniform float maxDist;
uniform float sphereRadius;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

How can I use Tessalation/Geometry Shaders to create more vertices in between points and offset the newly created vertices so they have the given length of the `sphereRadius` uniform.

I am not looking for a solution that does one subdivision for every line. I look for a solution that does as many subdivisions as needed to get a certain distance between points that does not exceed `maxDist`.

---

I am currently drawing like this:

```
glBindVertexArray(_vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, _size);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at writing a tessellation shader? EDIT - Sorry, I should have clarified, if you are using OGL 4 you can try using a Tessellation Evaluation Shader. [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation#Tessellation_evaluation_shader)

Comment: Yeah I already read that, sadly I cannot really translate OpenGL Wikis description into useful code. And the two tutorials that are linked to that article  do not help me either. All tutorials I found regarding Tessallation are processing triangles.
Edit: I know that I have to use Tessellation Control Shader and Tessellation Evaluation Shader, but I do not understand how...

Comment: The process of using TCSs and TESs doesn't change just because you're making lines. The general idea is the same either way.