# Drawing tessallated LineLoops in OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, tessellation

I am rendering some LineLoops on a sphere (borders on a planet) and want to tessallate them into shorter lines to prevent long lines clipping into the sphere.
Example:
[image]

Here is my current source code:
C++ draw call:

```
void Border::Draw() const
{
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);

    glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, _size);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400

in layout(location = 0) vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Tessallation Control Shader:

```
#version 400

layout (vertices = 2) out;

void main()
{
    if(gl_InvocationID == 0)
    {
        //get the distance between two points
        float dist = length(gl_in[0].gl_Position - gl_in[1].gl_Position);
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 1;
        //divide line in segments of size 1.0
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = abs(dist);
    }

    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

Tessallation Evaluation Shader

```
#version 400

layout (isolines, equal_spacing) in;

uniform float planetRadius;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vec4 p = mix(gl_in[0].gl_Position, gl_in[1].gl_Position, gl_TessCoord.x);

    //offset point so it is on the spheres surface
    p = normalize(p);
    p *= planetRadius;

    gl_Position = projection * view * p;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The tessallation doesn't seem to work like I expect it to work (documentation on isolines is also bad).

This is how it looked when I draw it with LineLoops and only Vertex/Fragment Shader:

[image]

and this is how it looks like after I implemented my tessallation:

[image]

The lines also do not look tessallated and have the same length as before.

Greetings Jhonny

Edit:
Found the solution myself. Look in answer section below to see it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to normalize the entire `vec4 p` and not just its `.xyz` part? Also you might have got isoline usage wrong, here's a good source: [http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2120983](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2120983)

Comment: Thank you the normalization was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem lies within the tessallation shaders inability to draw line strips. So if you hava a line strip defined by the points `{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}` it draws lines between:
    p1 -> p2
    p3 -> p4
    p5 -> p6

I fixed it by giving the shader every point 2 times, so my list looks like this:
`{p1, p2, p2, p3, p3, p4, p4, p5, p5, p6, p6, p1}`
The tessallation shader creates following lines:
    p1 -> p2
    p2 -> p3
    p3 -> p4
    p4 -> p5
    p5 -> p6
    p6 -> p1

My shaders now look like this:

TessControl:

```
#version 430

layout (vertices = 2) out;

void main()
{
    if(gl_InvocationID == 0)
    {
        float dist = length(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz - gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz);

        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 1;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = dist;
    }

    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
}
```

TessEval:

```
#version 430

layout (isolines, equal_spacing) in;

uniform float planetRadius;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    //only interpolate and normalize xyz coordinates. Thanks to @aslg
    vec3 p = mix(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz, gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz, gl_TessCoord.x);

    p = normalize(p);
    p *= planetRadius;

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(p, 1.0);
}
```